# Error Packing and Unpacking bytes in Python

Tags: python, struct, python-2.x

My code has an error(see below code) after I enter in a value. I can pack the bits but the unpacking doesn't work. Any suggestions? I don't fully understand the packing and unpacking and the documentation is a bit confusing.

```
import struct


#binaryadder - 
def binaryadder(input):
    input = int(input)
    d = struct.pack("<I", input)
    print d
    print type(d)
    d = struct.unpack("<I",input)
    print d 
#Test Pack 

count = 0
while True:
    print "Enter input"
    a = raw_input()
    binaryadder(a)
    count = count + 1
    print "While Loop #%s finished\n" % count
```

This code throws back the following error after I enter in a string:

```
Enter input
900
ä
<type 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PythonPractice\Binarygenerator.py", line 25, in <module>
    binaryadder(a)
  File "C:\PythonPractice\Binarygenerator.py", line 17, in binaryadder
    d = struct.unpack("<I",input)
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = struct.pack("<I", input)
```

This packs the input into a string; so the entered number `900` is packed into the string `'\x84\x03\x00\x00'`.

Then, a bit later, you do this:

```
d = struct.unpack("<I",input)
```

Now you attempt to *unpack* the **same** input, which is still `900`. Obviously, that doesn’t work since you need to unpack a string. In your case, you likely want to unpack `d` which is what you packed before. So try this:

```
unpacked_d = struct.unpack("<I", d)
```

`unpacked_d` should then contain the number that was `input`.

Comment: I see the input error but shouldn't this be packing input as an integer? When I type struct.unpack("<I">,d) in the shell I get '\x84\x03\x00\x00' instead of 'ä'

Comment: Okay, yeah, I have no idea where your `ä` comes from there. If you do struct.pack("<I", 900)` (900 being the value of `input` according to your output), you get `'\x84\x03\x00\x00'`. If you now unpack that string: `struct.unpack("<I", '\x84\x03\x00\x00')` you get back your `900`.

Comment: `print repr(d)` will display `'\x84\x03\x00\x00'`.  Printing `d` directly inteprets the bytes in the terminal encoding.  `\x84` is `ä` in the OP's terminal.